# NSUserDefaults sigsegv(11) exception

Tags: ios, delphi

The following code (Delphi, XE5, IOS) fails with SIGSEGV(11) exception call to stringforkey.
I am able to compile and excute successfully the example code (delphisettings), that appears to be exactly the same.
Just prior to this the call 
    result := lDefaults.boolForKey(NSStr(InName)); 
works fine.
My guess is it due some string length error.

```
var
  lDefaults: NSUserDefaults;
  lStr: string;
...
  lDefaults := TNSUserDefaults.Wrap(TNSUserDefaults.OCClass.standardUserDefaults);
  lStr := UTF8ToString(
    lDefaults.stringForKey(NSStr(InName)).UTF8String);
  result :=  UTF8ToString(lStr);
```

I revisited the example and on one occasion I also got the same exception.

Also I just noticed the example http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/29400 says its for delphi < 18.0. XE5 is 19.0.

So is there anything around tested for 19.0?

Comment: Why would you call Utf8ToString(Utf8ToString(...))? That looks very wrong.

Comment: That is the way the example works. stringforkey returns _Pansichar

Comment: @IanMcKinnon - actually: the stringForKey method returns a NSString; you then call its UTF8String method to get a _PAnsiChar; the _PAnsiChar is passed to UTF8ToString, with the result assigned to lStr; lStr is then passed to UTF8ToString again. (This isn't the reason for the segmentation fault mind.)

Comment: By the by - in answer to your last question, you can try my `CFPreferences`-based version of the same idea (http://delphi-foundations.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FMX%20Utilities/). If you want help with a `NSUserDefaults` version, then I'd suggest posting a compilable sample that reproduces the issue, given what you've posted so far doesn't compile in itself (obviously...), and is 'exactly the same' as the linked code in exactly the same way it is somewhat similar...

Comment: I gave up on it and have simply used the tinifile. Much simpler and works fine. Thanks Chris.